# Number of users on current page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've my application built on Laravel 4.1. In my application I want to get number of authentic users currently watching a particular page, like if the application has page1, page2. I want to know the number of users currently on page 1 vs. on page 2.

How can I implement this feature in laravel?

Comment: Store their session ID in a table along with a timestamp? Select those who have viewed the page within a predefined period of time (last 1 or 2 minutes?)

Comment: Don't you like Google Analytics? Isn't a PHP solution, but have more tools for analysis. Just an opinion...

Comment: I expect , who is currently watching the page not who viewed the page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very unique problem and there is not a straight solution to this anyway.

```
$users = count(glob(session_save_path() . '/*'));
```

Note that this just counts session files. It will undoubtedly contain stale/dead sessions that haven't been garbage collected yet.

A better way according to me would be if you create time stamps for each of your page and have every page issue and ajax call to the server every few seconds to update these timestamps.

So if a user is on a particular page, the page will keep sending requests to the server every few seconds and the time stamps will be updated.

You can then calculate the number of users on a particular page by querying the time stamps for the last minute or something.

Comment: Ok . It's a good idea . Let me try .